# How can I get Windows 7 to display drives with bars indicating drive data usage?

Tags: windows-7

Once our IT consultant sent me a screenshot showing bars to indicate the data usage of drives. I have a Windows 7 machine and my display only lists numbers for Total Size and Free Space usage of drives. How can I display the bars in the screenshot? (The IT consultant is no longer there to ask).

[image: Bars indicate data usage of drives]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the view to 'tiles'. You can right click on any empty spot on the windows explorer window, select 'view', then select 'tiles'.

If you want to change this to be the default view, follow the instructions found here:
http://www.digitalcitizen.life/configure-default-viewing-templates-windows-explorer-be-you-want-them

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Would never have realized the bars were tiles.

Comment: Every Windows 7 install I have done or used has this view by default?

Comment: I believe I set the default view to Details (I like this for folder listings), so Tiles is no longer my default.

Comment: You can set it for just the 'my computer' using this method and it will stick; I think you only need to change defaults if you want to change it for multiple views (like any folder with pictures in it view as thumbnails, etc). So you are probably all set.